# Get pure error message from form validation in Laravel?

Tags: php, angularjs, validation, laravel-4

I am developing REST services using laravel.I want to get exact error message from laravel form validation
controller

```
$validator = Validator::make(array('email' => Input::get('email')), array('email' => array('required', 'email')));
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->res_err_data['error'] = $validator->messages();
        return Response::json($this->res_err_data, 400);
    }
```

Error message

```
{
    "status": "2",
    "data": [],
    "error": {
        "email": [
            "The email field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to get email error message just `"The email field is required."` instead of `["The email field is required."]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Add following line after email field

  {{ $errors->first('email', '<div class="errorsetting">:message</div>') }}

Add following line after "$validator = Validator::make(array('email' => Input::get('email')), array('email' => array('required', 'email')));"

if ($validator->fails()) {

return Redirect::to('toyourpage')->withInput()->withErrors($validation->messages());

}
```

Comment: I am developing REST webservices,So need to display JSON instead of redirecting.1

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just use `array_map()` to change the structure:

```
$meessages = $validator->messages();
$this->res_err_data['error'] = array_map(function($errors){
    return isset($errors[0]) ? $errors[0] : null;
}, $messages);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this `$validator->errors()->first()` in your code like this

```
$validator = Validator::make(array('email' => Input::get('email')), array('email' => array('required', 'email')));
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $this->res_err_data['error'] = $validator->errors()->first();
    return Response::json($this->res_err_data, 400);
}
```